# Numeric values in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame which I use to call a function on all values from the column `p.inits` and plot them with the respective color from `cols`.

```
p.inits = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.9)
cols = c("red", "green", "blue")
data = data.frame(cbind(p.inits, cols))

foo = function (x) { print(1:x) }

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  print(data$p.inits[i]
}
```

The function `foo` shows that something is not working the way I expected, since the output is:

```
[1] 1 2
[1] 1
[1] 1 2 3
```

also, `p.inits` evaluates to `[1] 0.5 0.1 0.9`, whereas `data$p.inits` to this factor:

```
[1] 0.5 0.1 0.9
Levels: 0.1 0.5 0.9
```

My question is: what on God's green earth is happening? Why is the column `p.inits` not numeric? I just want to access the values `0.5, 0.1, 0.9`.

`as.numeric(as.vector(data$p.inits))` does the trick, but this seems highly overcomplicated. Is this really the correct way?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of doing `data.frame(cbind`, just do `data.frame(p.inits`.  You are converting to matrix first with `cbind` and `matrix` can hold only a single class, when convert to `data.frame`, the `character` class changes to `factor` as by default `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` and get `factor` class

Comment: That solves my problem. Thank you. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `data.frame` is better done with `data.frame` call alone and not by converting to `matrix` with `cbind` and then converting to `data.frame`.  The problem is how the `matrix` stores the elements as there is only a single `class` is normally allowed in `matrix`.  Here, there is a `character` column and so we have all the elements converted to `character`.  When we convert to `data.frame`, the default option `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` converts the `character` class to `factor` and that is the reason we have all `factor` class.

```
data <- data.frame(p.inits, cols)
```

should be the way

and if we don't need `factor` class then

```
data <- data.frame(p.inits, cols, stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
```